# Converting between NSData and base64 strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

What is the easiest and fastest code to do a conversion between `NSData` and a base64 string? I've read a bunch of solutions at SO and mostly they involve in adding another class etc. I found a great solution [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) but it's too complex.

Comment: All reasonable solutions are going to look something like the Matt Gallagher post you linked to.

Comment: Here's to finding Gallagher's library where people have mysteriously used `[NSData dataFromBase64String]` without linking

Comment: For some incomprehensible reason Apple has never provided "native" support for Base64, but all of the 3rd party kits are pretty much identical.  Just pick one.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Scroll down to the *Conclusion* section on [the page you linked](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) and [download the provided NSData+Base64 files](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip). Its the best solution I have seen so far and is incredibly easy to use. If you can learn anything about Cocoa, you can learn to use that project.

---

**Example**

```
NSString *originalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:originalString];  
NSLog([data base64EncodedString]);
```

The above will print out the original string after converting it to base64 and back to a normal unencoded string.

Comment: I have downloaded the two, so do I need to add that project to my or can I just simply drag the NSData + Base64?

Comment: You want to add the two files into your project. Generally when you see names like `NSData+Base64`, the first thing that should run through your head is that this is a category on the `NSData` class. In other words, you only call these new methods using `NSData`, not some new `Base64` class.

Comment: I believe, however, that you still need to import the category. Personally, I would recommend putting it into your precompiled header so you can use the methods on `NSData` from anywhere in your project.

Comment: how can I do that Ryan? mind giving me some pointers, I think that's the easiest way to do it

Comment: I would think the code sample in my answer would be sufficient... Can you be more specific with what pointers you need?

Comment: I downloaded that whole package you linked above, opened the project and drag the two files NSData+Base64.h and .m and then it gives me an error

Comment: one question the file has a base64.m, do I need that as well? because if I do it has a include <openssl/bio.h> and #import <Security/cssm.h> which gives me an error as it doesn't know how to find it. ALso the project has an external framework of lubcrypto.dylib, which I don't have

Comment: You should only have to import the header file to get it to work. In terms of a framework dependency, I am unaware of one with this particular project. Are you sure you're importing the header to be visible where you need it to be?

Answer (score 45):

As of iOS 7, `NSData` now directly provides this functionality with the new methods [`-base64EncodedDataWithOptions:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW37) and [`-base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW38). (The options let you specify that the string is/should be line-wrapped, the better to deal with email, and user-facing displays.)

Answer (score 44):

You don't need any custom implementation. Creating base64 from NSData is shown in other answers. There is opposite direction. From Base64 string to NSData:

```
 NSString *base64Encoded = @"some base64 string";
 NSData *nsdataFromBase64String = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Encoded options:0];
```

Comment: This was added in iOS 7/OSX 10.9 and it is hands down the best solution offered here. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithBase64EncodedString:options:).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this same class as provided by SUDZC

implementation was easy first I did an import

```
 #import "NSData+Base64.h"
```

then I was able to call my data.

```
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:strData]];
```

Comment: All I get ist 'NSData+Base64.h' file not found. 

Comment: @Martin I used the classes generated by the [sudzc](http://www.sudzc.com) lib,  it creates this class for you that you can then import in your implementation file (.m)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are more Base64 formats.

For example JWTs use a [URL safe format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

Answer (score 0):

Or you may take a look to the (quite new) [CryptoCompatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CryptoCompatibility/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project, I think there is a wrapper class for base64 operation. It is a MacOS sample but it uses the library libresolve.dylib with I think is available on iOS too (is see it at least here in iOS7).