# how to receive the image from url and how it post?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, xcode4.2

I am trying to receive the url image and post the image into base64 format.

i am worked out this way but i didn't find any solution.

my .h file

```
@interface urlconnection : NSObject
{
    id delegate;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSURL *url;
    // NSData * imageData;
    IBOutlet NSImageView * myimages; 
        //and also trying UIImageView also atleast i didn't receive the image  
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (retain) id delegate;

- (void)post: (NSString *)urlString;

@end
```

my implementation file is

```
- (void)post: (NSString *)urlString {
        myimages.image = [NSImageView imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevelopers.com/files/2010/03/iphone-sdk2.jpg" ]]];
        NSLog(@"image shown successfully");

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevelopers.com/files/2010/03/iphone-sdk2.jpg"]];  

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"image/" 
        forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imageData length]] 
        forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:imageData];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

please friends help me because i am new this concept

and please suggest the best tutorial for this concepts....

Comment: `myimages.image = [NSImageView imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...` should be `NSImage`, right? also, for base64 encoding see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999370/nsdata-to-base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post an image, you need a proper server webservice that is able to receive your image on server side..

Try this link that help you to  [upload your image from application](http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/upload-image-and-data-with-iphone-sdk/)

I think using asynchronous file downloading for image will be proper approach for downloading image since your code will freeze app until your image is downloaded.

You can try this [link.](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation) There might be better downloader examples then this.

Answer (score 1):

myimages.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL

```
    URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevelopers.com/files/2010/03/iphone-sdk2.jpg" ]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the image from an URL:

```
  yourImageView.image= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringContainningURL]]];
```