# Sandbox: bookmarkDataWithOptions and errors are nil without explanation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I am sandboxing my app. When I call `-bookmarkDataWithOptions: includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:` I receive `nil` without any explanation (the error object is `nil` too).

- The app is correctly signed
- I created these entitlements:

> ```
> <dict>
>   <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
>   <true/>
>   <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
>   <true/>
>   <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
>   <true/>
>   <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
>   <true/>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

- I'm creating the bookmark with this code:

> ```
> NSError *error = nil; 
>
> // nextfile is NSURL and comes from NSOpenPanel
>
> NSData *fileURLSecureData = [nextFile bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope 
>                                includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
>                                                 relativeToURL:nil
>                                                         error:&error]; 
>
> if (error) {
>     ALog(@"Error securing bookmark %@", error);
> }
> ```

I see, when I'm stepping through the code in the debugger, `fileURLSecureData` and `error`  are both `nil` after execution of `-bookmarkDataWithOptions: includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:`

I must be missing something. I have read and re-read forums and articles but I am unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `nextFile` isn't `nil`? 'cause that would explain both `error` and `fileURLSecureData` being `nil` here.

Comment: Have you seen the question I asked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259692/app-sandbox-document-scoped-bookmark-not-resolving-not-returning-any-error    I had a similar problem. Also, can you add the code where you get the URL from the `NSOpenPanel`? That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was trivial. In Xcode I inadvertently unchecked "Enable Entitlement" for the Dev configuration, leaving it checked for Release builds.