# How to generate vcard in iPhone using the address book contact details?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, vcf-vcard

I have an application where I want to import the address book details into vcard format. This is the code that I have done but the problem my email address, photo, organisation name, etc is not getting saved in vcard.

```
    -(NSString*)vcardrepresentation
{


        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [mutableArray addObject:@"BEGIN:VCARD"];
        [mutableArray addObject:@"VERSION:3.0"];

        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FN:%@ %@", self.contactlist.objContact.firstname,self.contactlist.objContact.lastname]];

        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ORG:%@",self.contactlist.objContact.companyname]];
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ADR:%@",self.contactlist.objContact.City]];

        if ([phoneArray count]!=0)
            [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEL:%@", phoneemail.phoneNumber]];

        if ([emailArray count]!=0)
        {
            [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EMAIL:%@",phoneemail.phoneNumber]];
        }
    if ([contactlist.objContact.Photo length]==0)
    {
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHOTO:%@",[UIImage imageNamed:@"man.png"]]];
    }
    else
    {

        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHOTO:%@",[UIImage imageWithData:contactlist.objContact.Photo]]];
    }


        [mutableArray addObject:@"END:VCARD"];

        NSString *string = [mutableArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];


        return string;

}
```

How can I save all the contact data in vcard format?

Answer (score 1):

Rani, I suggest the following pseudocode:

1. Get contact photograph as NSData (contactlist.objContact.Photo)
2. Convert NSData bytes to BASE 64 encoding scheme ([NSData to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999370/nsdata-to-base64), [base64EncodedString](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html))
3. Add encoded data and properties to vCard:

`[mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:%@", data]];`

For your information [vCard photographs](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcard-21.rtf) are images encoded with Base 64 scheme. There are 16 supported file formats including GIF and JPEG. Here's an example:

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=GIF: 
    R0lGODdhfgA4AOYAAAAAAK+vr62trVIxa6WlpZ+fnzEpCEpzlAha/0Kc74+PjyGM 
    SuecKRhrtX9/fzExORBSjCEYCGtra2NjYyF7nDGE50JrhAg51qWtOTl7vee1MWu1 
    50o5e3PO/3sxcwAx/4R7GBgQOcDAwFoAQt61hJyMGHuUSpRKIf8A/wAY54yMjHtz 
    ...
```

Comment: The correct value for the `ENCODING` parameter in vCard version 3.0 is `B` not `BASE64`.  `BASE64` is used in version 2.1.  The link to the 3.0 specs is: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2426.

Answer (score 1):

(1) It looks like you are setting the value of the `EMAIL` property to the phone number.

(2) The format of the `ADR` property is incorrect.  The correct format is to separate the address into its individual components, delimited by semicolons.  The format is:

```
ADR:post-office-box;extended-address;street-address;city;state;zip-code;country
```

If an address is missing a component (for example, it doesn't have a post office box), then an empty string should be used.  Therefore, an `ADR` value should always contain 6 semicolons.

(3) Semicolons, commas, backslashes, and especially newlines should be escaped in all vCard property values.  Semicolon and comma characters have a special meanings inside some properties (such as `ADR` and `ORG`), so it is especially important that these characters be escaped for these properties.  The characters are escaped with backslashes like so: `\;`, `\,`, `\\`, `\n`.

(4) Beware of folding.  The specs recommended that no line should exceed 75 characters (excluding newline).  If a line exceeds this limit, then it can be "folded" by inserting a newline and adding at least one tab or space character at the beginning of the line (as shown in @rjobidon's answer).

(5) The correct newline sequence for a vCard is `\r\n` not `\n`.