# iOS objective C: convert utf-16 to base64

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I read a string from a text input in objective C (iOS SDK), and treating it as UTF-16, encode the bytes to base64?

I'm struggling with both aspects, both treating the textbox's value as UTF-16 and then encoding these bytes to UTF-16.

I appreciate there are probably partial or similar questions to this on SO, I have searched (and read the various posts), but I'm an iOS/Objective C beginner and could really benefit from a complete example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `NSString` to a UTF16-encoded `NSData` by using

```
[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]
```

then convert the resulting `NSData` into Base64 using e.g. the answer from [Converting between NSData and base64 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999370/nsdata-to-base64).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get the value as an `NSString*` (which should be pretty simple), you can get UTF-16 using `-getCharacters:range:`:

```
unichar *buffer = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * [str length]);
[str getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
```

This will give you a `unichar*` buffer, which is a buffer of UTF-16 characters.

Alternatively, if you prefer working with `NSData*`, you can use

```
[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```