# How to convert Base64 string to NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, blob, nsdata

I have an iOS application (written in Swift) that retrieves data from a wcf service in JSON format. One of the data is an image stored as a **base64string**. However, I was not able to convert the **base64string** to **NSData**.

My main purpose is to convert **base64string** all the way to **blob** so that I could save that in the database. On the other hand, if you know at least part of it such as from **base64string** to **NSData** would be helpful.

Following code would give you the idea of my table

```
let ItemsDB = Table("Items")
let idDB = Expression<String>("ID")
let nameDB = Expression<String>("Name")
let catDB = Expression<String>("Category")
let uomDB = Expression<String>("UOM")
let priceDB = Expression<Double>("Price")
let imageDB = Expression<Blob>("Image")
let actDB = Expression<Bool>("Active")
```

Comment: B64 to NSData:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithBase64EncodedString:options: (sorry for the previous erroneous links)

Comment: @EricD. Thanks, by any chance do you know how to convert NSData to blob?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert from Base64 string to NSData

```
 let nsd: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: Image, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

To Convert to Blob

```
nsd.datatypeValue
```

Answer (score 11):

This works:

**Swift 3, 4 & 5:**

```
var data = Data(base64Encoded: recording_base64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```

**Swift 2:**

```
var data = NSData(base64EncodedString: recording_base64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

Comment: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" is the error I get

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of example you can find online but most of them are in Objective-c. For example, [Converting between NSData and base64 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999370/converting-between-nsdata-and-base64-strings)

It is pretty straight forward for you to use

`NSData(base64EncodedString: String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)`

Comment: By any chance do you know how to convert NSData to blob?

Comment: Sry, I never done that before but as my search result shows, you can use `yourNSData?.bytes` as blob when you insert into DB

Comment: Thanks but I found the answer... NSData.datatypeValue